# JNI java method found but calling it returns null (calling Java from C++)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to call the following Java method from C++

```
public Moves moves(final Context context)
```

which lives in a public final class called `Game`.  I used the following JNI code from C++ to find the method

```
jclass gameClass = env->FindClass("game/Game");
jmethodID moves_id = env->GetMethodID(gameClass,"moves","(Lutil/Context;)Lgame/rules/play/moves/Moves;");
```

and I checked that it is able to find the method id successfully.  The problem is that when I call the method, a null is returned in the following code (which I assume indicates an error).

```
jobject moves_obj = env->CallObjectMethod(game_object,moves_id, context_object);
```

where `game_object` is a jobject representing a `Game` object and `context_object` is a jobject representing a `Context` object.  I am new to JNI and I have not yet encountered a situation where the method was found but there was an error relating to calling that method.  Is there a good way to debug this?

EDIT:

It looks like adding

```
if(env->ExceptionCheck()){
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
}
```

can show any exceptions that occurred in the Java code that was being called and in my case there was an exception.  So there was actually no problem with the JNI code.

Comment: You need to call `CheckException()` or whatever it's called, or one of its friends, after every JNI API call.

Comment: @user207421 That's what I needed thanks.  Indeed it looks like there was an error thrown within the Java code I was calling

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer and when you are satisfied that it's the best sufficient answer, you can accept it.